# Issue with LI images in rows

Tags: css

So I have 29 images that I want to put into rows with css.  Currently I have 5 images per row, but for some reason, on the second row, there are only 2 images and then on the 3rd row it goes back to 5 images. If I have an even number of images (i.e. 30) it doesn't do this.  Here is my css:

```
h2.sfitemTitle {
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
}

ul.sfitemsList {
list-style-type:none;
}

li.sfitem {
display:inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
margin:15px;
text-align:center;
width: 150px;
float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
}
```

Any ideas on what I need to program in my css to prevent this?

Comment: Can you create an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: We need to see your HTML & CSS. JSfiddle please. Also it's not logical to use `display:inline-block` AND `float`

Comment: Yep--it was the float that was the issue. Thanks!